# How to insert XML in my Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, xml

How do I insert [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) in my Stack Overflow question?

I have tried the code, HTML and other options, but I was unable to get my XML code snippet included in my question in a readable format.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" >
    <DTS:ConnectionManager>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">DB2Source</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description"></DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">OLEDB</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:ObjectData>
            <DTS:ConnectionManager>
                <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Retain">0</DTS:Property>
                    <DTS:Password DTS:Name="Password" Sensitive="1"></DTS:Password>
                    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConnectionString">Data Source=develop;>
                </DTS:Property>
            </DTS:ConnectionManager>
        </DTS:ObjectData>
    </DTS:ConnectionManager>

    <DTS:ConnectionManager>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">SQLDest</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description"></DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">OLEDB</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:ObjectData>
            <DTS:ConnectionManager>
                <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Retain">0</DTS:Property>
                <DTS:Password DTS:Name="Password" Sensitive="1"></DTS:Password>
                <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConnectionString">Data Source=devc2400;</DTS:Property>
            </DTS:ConnectionManager>
        </DTS:ObjectData>
    </DTS:ConnectionManager>
</DTS:Executable>
```

Comment: I see you [were able to do that just fine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18091280/447356). :)

Answer (score 1):

Just like with code blocks, add 4 spaces to the beginning of every line

e.g.

```
<xml>
    <some>xml</some>
</xml>
```

Comment: Or select the text and hit ctrl+k. But not too hard... Keyboards have feelings too..